# asp.net mvc 3.0 Global Filter for SSL pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m in the process of creating a new C# asp.net mvc 3.0 project.

The web site will hold some ***public pages*** (such as: Home, about us, contact us, etc…) and hold some ***SSL enabled pages*** (such as: Login, Forgotpassword, Signup, in addition to *all* the pages in the application that the user will see after a successful authentication).

I’m curious to hear your thoughts (an opinion), before deciding on a particular approach.

I was thinking of using the Global Filter approach provided in MVC 3.0 in order to verify what are the pages being accessed…if the user is accessing ***public pages*** them make sure he’s in http:// if the user is accessing an ***SSL page*** then make sure it prints out the https://

Would the Global Filter approach be appropriate for what I’m trying to achieve?

Is there a good blog post for MVC 3.0 with such thing? (Currently googling).

Feel free to show me how or even propose an alternative.

Thanks
Sincerely

Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for...

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/08/19/how-to-switch-between-http-and-https-in-asp-net-mvc2.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sean!
The proposed solution seems even better then creating a Global Filter.

Put everything in the BaseController class…Humm…thanks!